# WebLogic 12c (12.2.1.4) with Hibernate 5.4

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, weblogic12c

I have an application deployed on WebLogic 12c (12.2.1.4) using Hibernate 5.2.18. Weblogic 12c doc references JPA 2.1 compatibility and Hibernate 5.3+ requires JPA 2.2. Can I prepend the JPA 2.2 API to my startup classpath and use Hibernate 5.3+ or should I stick with Hibernate 5.2 for the time being?

Comment: Do you use spring in app?

Comment: yes it's Spring 5.2

Comment: Do you remember what was the outcome of your experiments with Weblogic 12c +JPA 2.2?

Comment: @tporeba I just left it as is, WebLogic 12c assumes a JPA 2.1 API level, you can override it but it becomes a bit of a beast when you're attempting to mix J2EE spec levels, if you're on 12c I'd stick with the jars as-is unless there's some specific use case you need that forces you to update it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this configuration is possible.

To avoid conflicts with WebLogic built-in JPA capabilities you should do the following:

1. According to [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#orm-jpa)

> In a full Java EE environment, consider obtaining your `EntityManagerFactory` from JNDI. Alternatively, specify a custom `persistenceXmlLocation` on your `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` definition (for example, META-INF/my-persistence.xml) and include only a descriptor with that name in your application jar files. Because the Java EE server looks only for default `META-INF/persistence.xml` files, it ignores such custom persistence units and, hence, avoids conflicts with a Spring-driven JPA setup upfront.

You can use something like this in the spring context config.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>
    <!-- ... -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="DS" jndi-name="appDS" />
    <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
       <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/app-persistence.xml" />
       <property name="dataSource" ref="DS" />
    </bean>
    <!-- ... -->
</beans>
```

2. According to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/classloading.htm#WLPRG285)

> To configure the `FilteringClassLoader` to specify that a certain package is loaded from an application, add a `prefer-application-packages` descriptor element to `weblogic-application.xml` which details the list of packages to be loaded from the application.

You should add the following snippet to your `META-INF/weblogic-application.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-application>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <!-- ... -->
        <package-name>javax.persistence.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
</weblogic-application>
```